# Piecewise Functions and Supremums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &x < a\\
x + 3, & x \geq a
\end{cases}$ $\hspace{1cm}$ and $A = \left \{ f(x): x < a\right \}$

Is $\text{sup}\  A= f(a)$?

I suspect not because it is NOT the case that for any arbitrary positive number $f(a) - \epsilon < f(x)$ for $x \in A$. In other words, there exists epsilon such that $f(a) - \epsilon \geq f(x)$, thus contradicting that $\text{sup}\  A= f(a)$.

But then what *is* sup $A$?

Comment: the supremum would just be $a$ itself. It's an upper bound, and the smallest one, but it just leaves a "hole" in the graph

Answer (score 1):

For $x < a$ , $f(x) = x$.
So basically $A = \{f(x) : x <a \} = \{ x : x <a \}$, and the supremum of this set is a.